# How can I use Advanced Custom Field Option page in CSS Wordpress

Tags: css, advanced-custom-fields, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3f5P.jpg)

```html
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); //look carefully to this line
$primary_color = " get_field('primary_theme_color', 'option');";
?>
<style type="text/css">
  --primary-color: <?php echo $primary_color; ?>;
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
--primary-color: <?php the_field('primary_theme_color', 'option'); ?>;
</style>
```

Or read this Article:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/

Comment: After adding code the css file stopped working

https://prnt.sc/VczEXBa35cSB

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).